# I don't know why I cannot get the output I expected

Tags: java, sum

This is the input I suppose to get..but I didn't get it. Also, I'm also not sure my coding is even right since this is my first time.

> Enter the employee ID: 785
> Sum of first & last digit = 12
> Assigned to Team A
> Enter the employee ID: 53
> Sum of first & last digit = 8
> Assigned to Team A
> Enter the employee ID: 9128
> Sum of first & last digit = 17
> Assigned to Team B
> Enter the employee ID: 39998
> Sum of first & last digit = 11
> Assigned to Team B
> Enter the employee ID: 123456
> Count of Team A members = 2
> Count of Team B members = 2

However, instead, I'm getting this at the end:

> Count of Team A members = 0
> Count of Team B members = 0

How should I properly code a method to count the team members?

```java
package STIA1014Asg2.zip;  
import java.util.*;  


public class nn {
    public static int getDigits(int num) { return String.valueOf(num).length(); }
 
    public static int getLast(int num) { return num % 10; }
  
    public static int getFirst(int num) {
        int first = 0;
        while(num != 0) {
           first = num % 10;
           num /= 10; 
        }
        return first;
    }
    private static class Group {
        public List<Integer> teamA = new ArrayList<>();
        public List<Integer> teamB = new ArrayList<>();

        public Group() {
        }
    
        private void display() {
             System.out.println("Count of Team A members = " + teamA.size());
             System.out.println("Count of Team B members = " + teamB.size());
            }

        private void add(int id, boolean b) {
            
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      Group group = new Group(); 
      
      
      while(true) {
          System.out.print("Enter the employee ID: ");
          int id = scan.nextInt(); 

          int digits = getDigits(id); 
          if(digits > 5 || digits < 2) {  
              group.display();  
              break; 
          }

          int first = getFirst(id); 
          int last = getLast(id);   
          int sum = first + last;   
          System.out.println("Sum of first & last digit = " + sum); 
          
          if(sum % 2 == 0) {  
              group.add(id, true);
              System.out.println("Assigned to Team A");
          }
          else { 
              group.add(id, false);
              System.out.println("Assigned to Team B");
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` method could look that way :

```
   private void add(int id, boolean b) {

        if(b){
            teamA.add(id);
        }
        else{
            teamB.add(id);
        }
        
    }
```